# Distance between Transceiver and Receiver and AWGN

Tags: channel

Is there a relationship between the distance between the transceiver and the receiver and the AWGN?

When the distance between the transceiver and receiver increases, the AWGN level decreases?

Answer (score 2):

Although AWGN is *modeled* as being added by the AWGN channel (which by definition does nothing to the signal traversing the channel except add the white Gaussian noise), the truth of the matter is that most of the noise in the receiver is *thermal noise* generated by the circuitry in the front-end of the receiver. In comparison, the actual noise from the channel (say the $3^\circ K$ background radiation from the  Big Bang in a wireless or space channel) is usually quite negligible.  Although we ignore fine points re amplitude in mathematical models since we like to use and analyze  *linear receivers*, in actuality, the received signal (plus the noise generated in the front-end circuitry) is *amplified* in the IF circuitry before any signal processing begins, and so the noise in the IF circuitry and the back-end circuitry is usually negligible compared to the amplified noise coming from the front end.

So, the answer to the OP's question

> When the distance between the transmitted and receiver increases, the AWGN level decreases?

is *NO, the AWGN level stays the same*. What *does* decrease is the *signal-to-noise ratio* (SNR) at the receiver. But do try to understand that the decrease in SNR is due to a decrease in S because the *received* signal power is smaller due to the larger distance between transmitter and received; the N remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

No. When someone says "AWGN" they mean that: all the channel does is add noise.

What you describe is some form of *fading channel*, not AWGN.

Comment: Note that "AWGN" stands for additive white Gaussian noise.  Meaning -- it's white Gaussian noise that's added to the received signal.